# error: ‘HZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, cpu-usage, cpu-cycles

I am trying to setup `Dhrystone` where I am getting the following error.

**error:** ‘HZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)

I don't the significance of HZ variable. I can compile the code straightaway by commenting the code which includes HZ variable. But is it the right way to do. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Please provide the version

Comment: I have downloaded dhrystone-2.1

Comment: How did you compile the code? Try providing `-DHZ=60` in commandline.  or add it in `Makefile`

Comment: I am using the following command.                                   gcc dhry_1.c dhry_2.c -o dhrystone

Comment: After using -DHZ=60 it works.Could you let me know how you arrived at -DHZ=60 because I am seeing any value assigned to -DHZ works. Also want to know does HZ signify processor speed.

Comment: Its provided in `Makefile`. You should use `Make all`. To know more about `HZ`, read http://fossies.org/linux/privat/old/dhrystone-2.1.tar.gz/README.RER file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion it has worked